# if then statements in Windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I was using the following script to remove a specific local printer on user logout:

```
RUNDLL32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /n "DYMO LabelWriter 450" /dl
```

How could this be modified so that if the printer does not exist locally, the script terminates without throwing an error?

Comment: do you want to know how to do a if, or do you want to know how to do this specific if?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wmic printer get name /value | find "DYMO LabelWriter 450" && (
   RUNDLL32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /n "DYMO LabelWriter 450" /dl
)
```

This uses [conditional execution](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php)

Or simply

```
WMIC /INTERACTIVE:ON PRINTER where Name="DYMO LabelWriter 450" DELETE >nul 2>&1
```

, but this should be ran as administrator

Comment: +1, Oh yes, I much prefer the simpler 2nd solution. Although, don't you mean `where Name="DYMO LabelWriter 450"`?

Comment: I've never used DELETE. Should there really be `DELETE delete`? What is `/interactive` vs `/nointeractive`? Does it require to be run as administrator?

Comment: No the second `delete` is a typo.And yes again /interactive should be `on`.And yes ,it requires to be administrator :-)  . I should be more precise...